# Find an integer n such that $U(n)$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2⊕\Bbb Z_4⊕\Bbb Z_9$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Find an integer n such that $U(n)$ is isomorphic to $Z_2⊕Z_4⊕Z_9$

I have gotten this far:
I know $Z_2$ is isomorphic to $U(4)$ and $Z_4$ is isomorphic to $U(5)$. However, I'm having trouble figuring out what $Z_9$ is isomorphic to in regards to the U-group. I remember proving somewhere that for all integers $n\geq 3$, $|U(n)|$ is even. Since $|Z_9|=9$, which is odd, I can't see to find a $U$ group that $Z_9$ is isomorphic to.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: it is  known that $|U(n)|$ is the value Eulerphi(n), but Eulerphi(n) is always even

Comment: Yes, I know  - that is where I am running into trouble. Since I can't find a U group that is isomorphic, I am not quite sure how to proceed with this problem.

Comment: the good news is that $73$ is prime : D

Comment: I am not quite sure I follow @janmarqz.

Comment: @janmarqz $U_{73}$ is the wrong answer, though, since it is cyclic.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, how do you know that $Z_2+Z_4+Z_9$ is not cyclic?

Comment: @janmarqz Because I know the structure theorem for finite abelian groups. But also because there is no element of order $8$.

Comment: Ah . . .ok ok ok

Comment: still there are other candidates $U(91)$, $U(95)$, U(111)$ , $U(117)$ . . .

Comment: Plenty of candidates - you just need the nine to combine with either $4$ or $2$, which both can do. The smallest $5\cdot 3^3$ has the smallest prime divisors.

Comment: Makes much more sense. Thanks for all the help !!!!

Comment: ... $U(135)$ cool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_9\cong\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{36}.$

$2+1$ and $36+1$ are *distinct primes*, so $\mathbb{Z}_3\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{37}\cong \mathbb{Z}_{3.37}$ would work.

Similarly $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}_4\oplus \mathbb{Z}_9\cong \mathbb{Z}_4\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{18}$.

Then $4+1$ and $18+1$ are also distinct primes, so $\mathbb{Z}_5\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{19}\cong \mathbb{Z}_{5.19}$ would also work.

Comment: So the better problem would be *find all $n$ instead of one*.